# Question regarding first order logic

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

> Let $S,T$ be two sets (finite or infinite) of propositions over
> $\sum_{ }^{ }$, such that $S∪T$ is not satisfiable. Prove there exists
> a proposition α over $\sum_{ }^{ }$, such that for every structure
> $M$, if $M$ satisfies $S$ then $M$ satisfies $α$, and if $M$ satisfies
> $T$, then $M$ doesn't satisfy $α$.

I had to translate the question from my native language so if there is a mistake in the translation somewhere let me know. :)

The official solution of this question used the compactness theorem, but I wanted to know if I'm missing something in my solution because it seems pretty short. Maybe I have some gap in knowledge someone can help me fill?

The attempt:

Note that $S∪T$ is not satisfiable. Then $∃β∈S$ such that $\left\{β\right\}∪T$ is not satisfiable.
Let $α=β$. Let $M$ be a structure over $\sum_{ }^{ }$.

Assume $M$ satisfies $S$. Then as $α∈S$, $M$ satisfies $α$.

Assume $M$ satisfies $T$. Then as $\left\{α\right\}∪T$ is not satisfiable, then $M$ doesn't satisfy $α$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line "Then there exists $\beta \in S$ such that $\{\beta\} \cup T$ is not satisfiable" is incorrect.

Consider $T = \emptyset$, $S = \{P, \neg P\}$ where $P$ is a $0$-ary predicate. Then $T \cup S$ is not satisfiable, but there is no $\beta \in S$ such that $\{\beta\} \cup T$ is not satisfiable.

The correct proof is: Suppose $T \cup S$ is not satisfiable. Then $T \cup S$ is not finitely satisfiable. Then there exists $s_1, ..., s_n \in S$, $t_1, ..., t_m \in T$ such that $\{s_1, ..., s_n, t_1, ..., t_m\}$ is not satisfiable. Then in particular, define $\alpha = \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n s_i$. Then if $M \models S$, we see that $M \models \alpha$. And if $M \models T$, then this means $M \models t_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$, so it cannot be the case that for all $1 \leq j \leq n$, $M \models s_j$; then $M$ does not satisfy $\alpha$.

Comment: Hi I think I understand your solution. But my problem is, how do I come up with such a solution? What do I need to look for when I'm faced with a problem such as this?

Comment: @MathCurious It's just a matter of being familiar with the important theorems of the field and knowing when to apply them. In this case, the first thing that comes to mind when I hear that a set is unsatisfiable is the compactness theorem.

Comment: Great, thank you!